# How does one transfer funds between a French bank account and a US bank account?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, international-transfer, wire-transfer, france

Say Person 1 has a French bank account, and Person 2 has a U.S. bank account.
Person 1 wants to send funds to Person 2.
Person 1 can add a new person to their list of beneficiaries, but the French bank's website requires IBAN and BIC numbers, which are not numbers that the U.S. account has.

[image]

How can this transfer happen?

Answer (score 3):

Person 1 may walk into his bank and fill out a form for SWIFT payment.

Comment: Thanks @base64 but how about through the internet?

Comment: Person 1 may switch to a bank that has international exposure. e.g. HSBC

Comment: And what if that can't happen either? We're talking about trying to do this online with the current settings... How about putting a swift code into the fields required by the french bank?

Comment: Person 1 risks being charged 25-35 EUR for entering incorrect information. Plus I don't think the website would allow incorrect format for SEPA payment.

Comment: 25-35 EUR fine or buying plane tickets to go to france... one of them is cheaper ;)

Comment: @fabriced You don't need to be at the bank to submit the form. You can download the form or ask the bank to email it. You print and sign the form, then mail it to the branch in France.

Comment: What if the form isn't available to download online? What if there is no direct way to contact the bank to ask for a form? Contacting the bank, asking for mailed documents, etc, requires that Person 1 be in their country.
Isn't there a much simpler way to do this if both people open a PayPal account for example?

Comment: Does this transfer need to happen bank to bank directly, or can this be processed through a third party intermediary or an alternate form of transfer (such as Bitcoins)?

Answer (score 1):

If you send money from a typical French bank to a US bank, they're likely to take some fees and/or give an exchange rate worse than the interbank exchange rate.

[Revolut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolut) uses the [interbank exchange rate for EUR <-> USD on weekdays (Mon-Fri UTC)](https://www.revolut.com/en-FR/help/getting-started/exchanging-currencies/what-foreign-exchange-rate-will-i-get) and don't have any [fee](https://www.revolut.com/en-FR/legal/fees), so that's the cheapest option I am aware of. They do have a [limit of 6,000 EUR / month](https://www.revolut.com/en-FR/legal/fees) (reset on the 12th midnight CET of each month), above which they'll take a 0.5% conversion fee (unless you  purchase the premium/metal accounts, in which case there is no limit).

Other options: [N26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N26_(bank)) (I haven't tried it) and TransferWise (more expensive than Revolut: they charge a 0.5% fee on the conversion).

---

Fee comparison from https://www.starlingbank.com/send-money-abroad (Revolut is the best in the benchmark even though it was done by a competitor, starlingbank):

[image]